# getElementId returns null or undefined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, getelementbyid

I'm using PHP, AJAX with jQuery so when this if statment process it will show all the players that have been selected along with placing a remove button and a `onclick="removeplayer(test);"`. But when I click the "Remove player" button I will either get a `null` or `undefined`.

PHP

```
   if(count($_SESSION['players'],COUNT_RECURSIVE) == $_SESSION['savedPlayers'] )
{

    foreach($_SESSION['players'] as $key => $value){
    echo "Player #:  . $key . ; Player Name: . $value . \n";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"" . $key . " \" id=\"" .  $value . "  \" value=\"Remove\" onclick=\"removePlayer(" . $value . ");\"> <br />";
    }

    echo "Max number of Players";
}
```

And my JavaScript is basic now because I'm just trying to make sure I'm getting the id passed correctly. I eventually will add jQuery that will remove the player from the list.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function removePlayer(test){    

    alert(test);
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because that you have not enclosed the $value within quotes try this

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"" . $key . " \" id=\"" .  $value . "  \" value=\"Remove\" onclick=\"removePlayer('" . $value . "');\"> <br />";
```

Comment: Without those quotes, JavaScript expects that you're passing an undefined global variable; with the quotes, you're passing `$value` as a String, which is what you want to do.

Comment: Ah i see now. Thank you for pointing out my mistake! It works now. :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

You're generating malformed Javascript - by forgetting to surround your onclick function call with quotes. Given you've got a seriously terminal case of "leaning toothpick syndrome" in your code, try outputting the HTML like this:

```
    $safe_value = json_encode($value);
    echo <<<EOL
Player #: $key  Player Name: $value
<input type="button" name="$key" id="$value" value="Remove" onclick="removePlayer($safe_value);"><br />
EOL;
```

Note the use of json-encode to ensure that the $value is actual proper JS data. Using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s for this is deal, as it eliminate any need to escape any quotes in the text you're outputting, plus allows direct insertion of variables.